# Inserting into an ordered linked list - Java ADT

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, adt, insertion

Hi this is my code for inserting an item...i was told it failed when inserting at the beginning of the list but don't understand why or how to fix it.

```
public void put(K key, V value){
    OrderedLinkedListEntry <K,V> item = new OrderedLinkedListEntry (key, value);

    OrderedLinkedListEntry <K,V> current = head;
    OrderedLinkedListEntry <K,V> previous = null;

    if(current == null){
        head = item;
        numItems ++;
        return;
    }

    while(current != null){
        int result = key.compareTo(current.getKey());
        if(result == 0){
            current.setValue(value);
            return;
        }else if (result < 0){
                  item.setNext(current);
                  if (previous != null){
                  previous.setNext(item);
                  }
                  numItems ++;
                  return;
              }

        previous = current;
        current = current.getNext();

    }
```

Comment: `previous` is null when the key to insert is less than the key in the head item.

Answer (score 0):

In your solution, `previous` is null when the key to insert is less than the key in the head item.

Make a special case for the new key being less than the key in the head:

```
if (key.compareTo(head.getKey() < 0) {
   item.setNext(head);
   head = item;
   return;
}
```

You also need to handle the case in which the key is larger than the one in the last item (the `result > 0` case).